# How to add first 'n' elements to a dataframe based on number of rows per group in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, sparklyr

I have a `sparklyr` dataframe  `df` that looks like this:

```
`id  label1   label2  label3  output
 1    car      1       dev     40
 1    jeep     1       test    50
 2    car      2       dev     40
 3    suv      1       dev     50
 3    suv      2       dev     60
 3    suv      2       dev     75
 3    suv      2       dev     70
```

I also have a vector which is of fixed length

```
vector = c(1,4,3,7)
```

I want to add a new column `vector_val` to `df` depending on the number of rows per `id, label1, label2 and label3`so that the first `n` values in vector are filled in `vector_val` where `n` = number of rows per each group

I tried this:

```
df <- (df %>% arrange(id) %>% group_by(id, label1, label2, label3) %>% mutate(n_records=n()) %>% mutate(vector_val = rep(vector, length=n_records)))
```

This returns an error:

> Error in eval_bare(call, env) : object 'n_records' not found

Expected output is:

```
`id  label1   label2  label3  output vector_val
 1    car      1       dev     40     1
 1    jeep     1       test    50     1
 2    car      2       dev     40     1
 3    suv      1       dev     50     1 
 3    suv      2       dev     60     1
 3    suv      2       dev     75     4
 3    suv      2       dev     70     3
```

Comment: Please share expected output

Comment: Why the last 3 values are 1, 4 and 3 when they have exactly the same id, label1, label2 and label3?

Comment: Because we have 3 rows in that group. The last 3 rows have only 1 unique combination of id, label1, label2 and label3. So the number of rows for this unique combination is 3. Because it is 3, I need to add the first 3 numbers of vector to the new column vector_val. The first 3 numbers of vector are 1, 4 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = read.table(text = "
id  label1   label2  label3  output
1    car      1       dev     40
1    jeep     1       test    50
2    car      2       dev     40
3    suv      1       dev     50
3    suv      2       dev     60
3    suv      2       dev     75
3    suv      2       dev     70
", header=T)

library(tidyverse)

vector = c(1,4,3,7)

df %>%
  group_by(id, label1, label2, label3) %>%           # for each combination
  summarise(n_records = n(),                         # count number of records
            output = list(output)) %>%               # keep output values in a list
  mutate(vector_val = list(vector[1:n_records])) %>% # use number of records to get corresponding vector elements and store them in a list
  unnest() %>%                                       # unnest columns
  ungroup() %>%                                      # forget the grouping
  select(-n_records)                                 # remove column


# # A tibble: 7 x 6
#      id label1 label2 label3 output vector_val
#   <int> <fct>   <int> <fct>   <int>      <dbl>
# 1     1 car         1 dev        40          1
# 2     1 jeep        1 test       50          1
# 3     2 car         2 dev        40          1
# 4     3 suv         1 dev        50          1
# 5     3 suv         2 dev        60          1
# 6     3 suv         2 dev        75          4
# 7     3 suv         2 dev        70          3
```

Comment: I am getting an error saying "Error in eval_bare(call, env) : object 'n_records' not found"

Comment: I assume you managed to successfully run the above solution, but you get an error when you run your whole dataset? Which line is producing that error? The `mutate`?

Comment: Yes, the code above works fine. But I see that my data.frame is not a R data.frame but rather it is a sparklyr tbl. If I convert the sparklyr tbl to R data.frame, this code works fine. But doesn't work with sparklyr tables.

Comment: Oh ok! That makes sense. Does it take time to do this conversion? Are you happy using this code?

Comment: It does take some time for conversion. But I guess there are no better alternatives :-)

Comment: I would expect `sparklyr` and `dplyr` to work smoothly without any problems. Some examples here: https://spark.rstudio.com/dplyr/ Can you convert this small dataset above to a sparklyr table and check if the code works?

Answer (score 0):

A shorter solution with 'tidyverse' too, possibly faster:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id,label1,label2,label3) %>%
  mutate(vector_val=vector[row_number()]) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 7 x 6
# id label1 label2 label3 output   val
#  <int> <fct>   <int> <fct>   <int> <dbl>
#1     1 car         1 dev        40     1
#2     1 jeep        1 test       50     1
#3     2 car         2 dev        40     1
#4     3 suv         1 dev        50     1
#5     3 suv         2 dev        60     1
#6     3 suv         2 dev        75     4
#7     3 suv         2 dev        70     3
```